# hunchentoot fatal error encountered in SBCL SIGABRT received

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, hunchentoot

while installing hunchentoot (and subsequently loading it), I have the error:

```
* (ql:quickload :hunchentoot)
To load "hunchentoot":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    hunchentoot
; Loading "hunchentoot"
....fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 43052(tid 0xb57dc0):
SIGABRT received.

Welcome to LDB, a low-level debugger for the Lisp runtime environment.
ldb>
```

I have locally built SBCL, using `./make.sh --fancy` flag to have threads on my macOS

```
% sbcl --version
SBCL 1.5.9
```

mac os:

```
% uname -a
Darwin <m/c name> 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64


% sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.1
BuildVersion:   19B88
```

Before I file it as bug, I post here to see if there's a known solution around.

Comment: Possible this is because you need to update your SBCL version, I had the same issue and resolved it with an update.

Comment: at the time, 1.5.9 has been the latest release. I can try with now released 2.0.0