# How to debug quickloaded library in sbcl

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I’m running into the exact same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270472/hunchentoot-fatal-error-encountered-in-sbcl-sigabrt-received), and I was wondering: given that sbcl drops you into a debugger repl when this happens, what is the best way to go about troubleshooting what’s going on? Are there resources out there for how to debug quickload libraries? If so, my brief google searching hasn’t found them.

Comment: which debugger? SLIME or LDB. Have you tried this outside of Slime from the command line?

Comment: LDB. My friend helped me out here: we ran a stack trace (after looking up commands in LDB with '?') and figured out that my SBCL version was outdated and that I needed to install openssl on my machine.

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear that it is sorted